# Android: EditText with syntax highlighting

Tags: android, android-edittext, highlighting

How to make EditText with syntax highlighting? There are ready solutions? 
HTML tags to insert as it seems to me, is not the best option, the app will slow down.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987660/android-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    final String FUNCTION = "function";
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {} 

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int index = s.toString().indexOf(FUNCTION);
        if (index >= 0) {
            s.setSpan(
                    new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN),
                    index,
                    index + FUNCTION.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
});
```

Refered [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668792/how-to-implement-a-simple-syntax-highlighting-method-for-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use like this .,

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    final String FUNCTION = "function";
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int index = s.toString().indexOf(FUNCTION);
        if (index >= 0) {
            s.setSpan(
                    new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN),
                    index,
                    index + FUNCTION.length(),
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
});
```

please try this , this may be helpful .